# loss of precision when operating on a pandas dataframe with NaN values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, precision

I have a pandas dataframe where i would like to subtract two column values:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Label":["NoPrecisionLoss"],
                   "FirstNsae":[1577434369549916003],
                   "SecondNsae":[1577434369549938679]})
print(df.SecondNsae - df.FirstNsae)
```

The result of subraction is the correct `22676`.

Now, when the input dataframe gets a second row with a `nan` value in it:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"Label":["PrecisionLoss","NeedsToBeRemoved"],
                   "FirstNsae":[1577434369549916003,np.nan],
                   "SecondNsae":[1577434369549938679,66666666666666]})
```

This `nan` value is nasty so we will remove the row that contains it:

```
df2 = df2[np.isfinite(df2.FirstNsae) & np.isfinite(df2.SecondNsae)]
```

Let's convert the `FirstNsae` column back to being an `int` (`FirstNsae` is assigned to be `float` because of the `nan` value in the second row):

```
df2 = df2.astype({"FirstNsae":int})  # this is futile since precision as already been lost
print(df2.SecondNsae - df2.FirstNsae)
```

Printing the difference between the two columns produces `22775`.

How can i avoid losing precision when constructing dataframes with extremely large integers in 
possible presence of `nan`'s?

Thank you!

Comment: Perhaps before you put the data into the `FirstNsae` column, you should intercept the `np.nan` values and put things into two separate `DataFrame`s. That way, when the non-`nan` values are cast, they will be cast as integers and you won't lose precision. But I wonder if you could just use a higher precision float type, e.g. `float64` rather than `float32`?

Comment: One way is to make as `dtype=object`: `df3 = pd.DataFrame(..., dtype=object)`

Comment: I would recommend using `[ ]` for column access, instead of the dot/`.`/attribute style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To elaborate on piRSquared's answer (in the comments to the original question), here is am approach that has solved the original issue:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"Label":["PrecisionLoss","NeedsToBeRemoved"],
                   "FirstNsae":[1577434369549916003,np.nan],
                   "SecondNsae"[1577434369549938679,66666666666666]},
                   dtype=object)
df2 = df2[np.isfinite(df2.FirstNsae.astype(float)) & 
          np.isfinite(df2.SecondNsae.astype(float)]

print(df2.SecondNsae - df2.FirstNsae)
```

prints `22676`!

Update:  Since Panda's version 1.0.0, this is not an issue anymore.  Integer values are allowed to be NaN.  https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.0.0/user_guide/missing_data.html#missing-data-na

Comment: I think you could use `Int64` as the dtype, too.